# Linux Ubuntu 20.4 version update error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My operation system in Linux Ubuntu.
Whenever I need to install something and I need to update my system, this error occurs. What should I do?

[image: Unable to lock directory]

Comment: Is anything running in the background trying to update things?  `ps -ef | grep -E 'apt|dpkg'` ... please add the output of the command to your question (and preferable coy & paste text, rather than a screenshot).

Comment: No, nothing is running. This error always occurs.

Comment: How about `sudo lsof | grep  /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`?

Comment: So, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Is there any output from the last command?

Comment: Does `ps 1694` show anything other than the header line? If not, you can remove the lock and run `apt-get update` again.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: maybe a `sudo systemctl stop packagekit` will stop the daemon which is blocking the access → https://askubuntu.com/a/1090555